# Windows Form Table Adapter Insert Query into Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, windows-forms-designer, tableadapter

I feel stupid for having to ask this but for some reason I can't get my insert query to actually insert the data into the table in access. I have done this many times while developing .NET applications using Sql Server but I can't figure out what I need to to for this windows form and Access. I am trying to insert data from textbox's where the user inputs data and saves it however I have tried multiple variations of executing the query and the table still doesn't have any data in it. This is not a problem with my connection string because I am able to run a select query and retrieve data from the table just fine.

My Insert Query is

```
INSERT INTO Contact (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)
```

I am trying to call this query in a Button_Click event

```
Me.ContactTableAdapter.InsertQuery(NameTxt.Text, PlaceTxt.Text)
```

I have also tried

```
Me.ContactTableAdapter.InsertQuery(FirstName:=NameTxt.Text, LastName:=PlaceTxt.Text)
```

and I have tried assigning the textbox values to variables and then placing the variables as the parameters and still no error but no insert.

Comment: Are you using this `TableAdapter` to `.Fill` a `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes sorry I said select query but I'm calling it from the .fill. I also believe that I finally found the solution, My connection string was not using an exact path it was using Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False; which was causing problems

Comment: Or I was at least not seeing the changes made to the table in the file that I was looking at but I changed the path to my datasource file and everything seems to work